# I'm having trouble with buttons and IRQ handler in keil uVision(STM32F103RBT6)

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupt, keil

Sorry for asking such a basic question, I am a beginner to ARM programming. I'm currently struggling with a lab exercise.

I was supposed to: Use the on-board button (PC13) to switch on and off the on-board LED (PA5). When the button is pressed, the LED is on. When the button is released, the LED is off.

The code below can be built, but it doesn't produce the result I wanted. In fact, nothing happens when I push the button.

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header
#include "stdbool.h"                 // For Boolean data type

#define BUTTON_RCC_GPIO  RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC
#define BUTTON_GPIO       GPIOC 
#define BUTTON_GPIO_PIN   GPIO_Pin_13

int main(void) {

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(BUTTON_RCC_GPIO, ENABLE); 


    //GPIO set up for PA5 (on board LED)
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure; 
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz; 
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP; 
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    //Timer 2 set up
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timerInitStructure;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;  
    timerInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_Period = 0;  
    timerInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0; 
    timerInitStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &timerInitStructure);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);

    TIM_TIxExternalClockConfig(TIM2, TIM_TIxExternalCLK1Source_TI2, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising, 0);

    //Enable update event for Timer2
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

    while(1);

    static char state = 0;
}

static char state = 0;

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) { 
    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET) { 
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5); 
            state = 1; 
        } else {
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5);
            state = 0;
        }
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update);
}
```

Edit: I have modified my code heavily, I decided not to use timers at all.

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header
#include "stdbool.h"

//TI2 PA1 Tim2 Ch2
#define BUTTON_RCC_GPIO   RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA
#define BUTTON_GPIO   GPIOA
#define BUTTON_GPIO_PIN   GPIO_Pin_13

#define L3_RCC_GPIO  RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA
#define L3_GPIO      GPIOA
#define L3_PIN     GPIO_Pin_5


static bool wait = true;

int main(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    // GPIO clock for I/O
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(BUTTON_RCC_GPIO, ENABLE);
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(L3_RCC_GPIO, ENABLE);

    // Configure I/O for L3
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = L3_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(L3_GPIO, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    while(1) {
                if(BUTTON_GPIO_PIN==true)
                {
                    GPIO_SetBits(L3_GPIO, L3_PIN);
                }else
                {
                    GPIO_ResetBits(L3_GPIO, L3_PIN);
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you're not checking the PC13, ever. You are not even setting it properly. There is just section about PA5 and setting it as an push pull output. But no input configured at all

Comment: If you can improve on your problem, you should edit your question so you focus it more and more, pointing out aspects that you found out along your way.

Answer (score 0):

*You didn't write this explicitly, but I assume your lab exercise is using the
[NUCLEO-F103RB](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf), where you find the 
[STM32F103RBTx](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103rb.pdf) controller equipped with a user push button at PC13 and a user LED at PA5 - I hardly think another brand creats a PCB with the very same properties... :-)*

---

As KIIV already pointed out in the comment, the reason you aren't seeing the LED change when the button is pressed, is that the controller input pin the button is connected to (PC13) isn't even checked.

Instead, the output state (PA5) for the LED is toggled in an ISR triggered by the interrupt of a timer (TIM2). 
The timer configuration (which may be incomplete, I can't tell from reading your code snippet alone) is triggered by rising edges at an external clock source at event `TI2`, which is tied to channel `TIM2_CH2` (available for pins `PA1` and `PB3`, for which I don't see any init code, however).

---

Some lines are redundant (the invocations to `RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd()` and the definitions of `state`, which will shadow each other...).

I have the impression that this code is not yet near to completion, but it may be helpful for you to first study what you want to achieve with the program, and what you are going to achieve by which section of your code. Then, finding the right solution for each detail is more a matter of studiousness and looking up the right datasheets (see links above).